# Gentoo: how to set hostname for local network?

Tags: gentoo, hostname

I'm used to debian/raspbian, setting the hostname for a computer is easy as:

```
/etc/hostname:

my-computer
```

and

```
/etc/hosts:

127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   my-computer
```

After these changes and a restart, I can `ssh username@my-computer.local` from any other machine on my local network.

I am having a really hard time getting this behavior on a new gentoo system. I've tried a few other settings from 2-3 year old posts on the gentoo forums with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ssh username@my-computer.local` to work, two things must be in place:

- `my-computer` must be running `avahi-daemon` or some other implementation of multicast DNS (mDNS for short). This will periodically announce the current hostname & IP of the computer to the local network, and will respond with that information if some other device in the local network asks for it. The announced name will be of the form `<short hostname>.local`.
- the computer with the SSH client must include `mdns`, `mdns4_minimal` or similar mDNS hostname resolution module listed on the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. This makes the glibc's hostname resolution function actually use mDNS as one possible source of hostname/IP information.

mDNS is compatible with the Apple's Bonjour system, and apparently Microsoft may have some support for it too - although modern versions of Windows seem to prefer WS-Discovery, another multicast-based protocol, for a similar purpose.

The top-level DNS domain `.local` is now reserved for mDNS use, so it should not be used for regular private DNS domains any more. However, for the sake of backwards compatibility, there is some support to allow names with three or more parts (e.g. `<hostname>.something.local`) to still work with regular DNS; two-part names (`<hostname>.local`) will be resolved by mDNS on mDNS-aware systems.

Comment: Yes! I didn't have avahi installed or running yet. I got my desired behavior to work after installing and adding rc-service, instructions here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Avahi